# How to make my function output data// Error: built-in method title of str object at 0x000001CC17CF99B0

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Can someone look at this function and explain to me why its not outputting a title on my html page?

Function

```
@app.route('/favorite/<username>')
def show_fav(username):
"""return all  favorite movies for specific user"""

cursor.execute(f"select * from Likes where username='{username}'")
details=cursor.fetchall()
for row in details:
    movie={ "ID": row[0],"Title": row[1],"Actors": row[2], "Plot": row[3], "Username": row[4]}

return render_template('favorite.html', username=username, movie=movie)
```

What this function outputs in ipython:

```
    (Pdb) movie
   {'ID': 26, 'Title': 'Power', 'Actors': 'Omari Hardwick, Lela Loren, Naturi Naughton, Joseph Sikora', 'Plot': 'James "Ghost" St. Patrick, a wealthy New York night club owner who has it all, catering to the city\'s elite and dreaming big, lives a double life as a drug kingpin.', 'Username': 'NurseJackie'}
```

Output

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
  {% block content %}

  <h1>Your Favorite List</h1>

  <ul>
{% for movies in movie %}
  <li><a class="p-3 text-white" href="/movies/{{ movie.id }}">
        Movie: {{ movies.Title}}</a>
        <small>Recommended By {{movies.username}}</small>

  </li>
{% endfor %}

</ul>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: In your line before title you wrote movie.id instead of movies.id

Comment: That is  a link that will show data regarding the movie if its clicked. It would show the actor, plot... This page will show the movies that the user has recommended by Title.

Comment: This is output : Movie: <built-in method title of str object at 0x000001C606415470> Recommended By

Comment: You have a typo just look at it. You can't have `movie.id`. It has to be `movies` since you're looping over `movie` not `movies`. Check your code